# "Marking" Pointers in C with "attributes"

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, buffer, bit

I have a huge buffer allocated with malloc on the heap, i want to write a custom allocator to allocate space from that buffer.

My question is now, if there's a way to "mark" some regions as "allocatable", "writable" and "reserved" in that buffer, like in Kernel Development.

An example, we've a buffer with 6 elements, how could i mark elements 2-5 as "reserved"?

```
   [0][1][2][3][4][5]
```

Could it be possible with flags, a Bit Manipulation or something?
Or could i mark the pointer?

Comment: You probably need to add metadata such as linked list pointers, size, etc.

Comment: Have some data structure aside to keep the records. Forget about bit manipulation for now.

Comment: An array of 'struct` (or a linked list) that includes a flag in each instance that you can set to indicate allocation allowed, or not.

Comment: It would probably be easier to implement a block pool rather than a byte pool.

Comment: Wouldn't have linked lists a huge impact on performance?

Comment: When you talk about performance, you have to compare with *something*. So, "huge impact" comparing to what?

Comment: @Lazcano In your question, you didnt mention any constraints or requirements. By not telling us you will not get the right answers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! :)

@EugeneSh. - compared to malloc.
I'll follow AndersK. advice!

Comment: If you want to compete with standard `malloc` you might want to first look at it's implementation. Which is, by the way, can vary pretty much.

Comment: Calling malloc as compared to say statically defined memory on the stack, is a speed hit on performance.  True whether the pointer is contained in an array of struct, or in a linked list.

Comment: AFAIK FreeBSDs' implementations are one of the greatest, if not the bests.

Comment: @Lazcano - Just an FYI, when wanting to send a text to someone specifically, in the comment box begin with using the `@` symbol, immediately followed by the users alias.  For example, `@ryyker` will cause a linked notice to appear at the top of the SO page, notifying me that someone has commented, allowing me to click that notice and see the comment. :)

Comment: @ryyker Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something as simple as an array of `struct` (or a `linked list`) that includes a flag in each instance that you can set to indicate allocation allowed, or not.
For example, using a flag and ambiguous typing (`void *`):

```
typedef struct {
    BOOL alloc; //set TRUE to allow or FALSE to disallow further allocation
    void *space;
    //other members
}BUF;
```

Create an array of `BUF`, and set the `alloc` member to `TRUE` or `FALSE` to set an instance be no longer accessible to changing its memory.  Of course this would occur after initial memory had been allocated during initialization.

Or another possibility using `enum` of types, in conjunction with a `union`:

```
typedef enum {
    _INT,
    _UINT,
    _CHAR,
    _UCHAR,
    ... //other types
}TYPE;

typedef struct {
    BOOL alloc; //set to allow or disallow further allocation
    TYPE type;  //flag to track type being used in instance
    union {
        char *cMem;
        unsigned char *ucMem;
        int *iMem;
        unsigned int *uiMem;
        ... // other members

    char *space;
}BUF;
```

Comment: Why `char *`?  Maybe `void *`?

Comment: A void* would fit better, as it's suitable for most cases. My reps are too low for an upvote, I'm sorry but i appreciate your answer!

Comment: @Lazcano - no problem.  By the way, a union of types could also be included in the struct representing the `type` that is needed.  (But edit shows Fiddling Bits suggestion)

Comment: That's right. Personally i prefer `void*` with explicit casting.

Answer (score 0):

Convert number of buffers in to bit array of unsigned int and use index of memory to mark it.
E.g.: unsigned int allocatable [((x) +31)>>5];
similar for writable and reserved.

Comment: Why `((x) +31)>>5`? Can you explain?

Comment: The buffer is a single buffer, which acts as the "heap". This way i have almost a perfect control of memory usage and can properly align memory.

Comment: Suppose X is max count of buffers, e.g.: 120 then allocatable[(120+31)>>5) will be allocatable[30].
If you allocate memory for index 4 then set allocatable[index >>5] |= (1<<(index &0x31), this way can be used to set and reset when required. (1 or 0)